# Android SDK: System Setting

Tags: java, android, networking, sdk, port

How can i set the System Port and Proxy?
Is there any command in java that can do that?
If not, how can i change it with superuser permission?
I have tryed a lot of codes, but no one worked for me.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
String myProxy=Proxy.getDefaultHost() ; 
        int myPort=Proxy.getDefaultPort(); 
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(myProxy,myPort,"http"); 
        client.getParams().setParameter (ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
```

try giving this within your java file. before that change your proxy settings in emulator!

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is not persistent.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "192.x.x.x"); 
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", "myuser"); 
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", "mypassword");
```